# How do I retrieve a path in Neo4jClient?

Tags: .net, neo4jclient

I've recently started using Neo4JClient for my .NET integration and I have (eventually) figured most things out. However, this one's stumped me.

I'm interested in getting paths back from a Cypher query, preferably in a POCO object so I can work on a front end for these queries.

So my question essentially is how do I do this in Neo4JClient? And if I can't, do any of the other Neo4J .NET clients support this?

A sample cypher query:

```
start n = node:idx(id="{id}")

MATCH p=(n)-[:RELATED_TO*0..3]-()

RETURN p;
```

So, I want all nodes around a specific node with both incoming and outgoing relationships to a depth of 3. There's another type of query too, but it uses withs and I need to find out if/how Neo4JClient supports that (another question there though).

Up until now, I've been using Gremlin with open and closed sets to populate a custom object with information on it's sub-relationships. It's by no means efficient, hence why I'd like to do it with paths somehow. The customobject in question looks a little like this.

```
public class ConnectedNode : BaseNode
{
    public List<NodeRelation> RelatedNodes { get; set; }

    public ConnectedNode()
    {
        RelatedNodes = new List<NodeRelation>();
    }
}

public class NodeRelation
{
    // ... various properties for relationship payload type stuff
    public ConnectedNode RelatedNode { get; set; }
    public RelationshipDirection Direction { get; set; }
}
```

I'm happy for anything that pulls back the node and relationship data on the path I'm looking for as long as it's efficient.

Comment: Do you have an example query you want to get the paths for? i.e. what you're trying?

Comment: @Chris, yeah, sure. I'll amend my answer with a sample query.

By you asking, can I guess that it supports some paths but not others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up working out the answer to this problem and have written a [blog post](http://craigbrettdevden.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/retrieving-paths-in-neo4jclient.html) on the subject. But so as you don't have to read the post for the jist of it...

First, extract the nodes and relations of the path using the EXTRACT function. This will give you a 2-column result. Encompass this 2-columned result in a POCO of your own choosing that takes a list of nodes and RelationshipInstances. Then retrieve your query into this kind of object using a Projection. Voila!

Hope this helps, it helped me.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted in the end, and a good post about it too

Comment: Excellent post! I just had this very same issue and I'm glad I found your question. I'll use this technique in my Associativy graph knowledge base platform.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
ICypherFluentQueryReturned<PathsResult> query
    = graphClient.Cypher
                    .StartWithNodeIndexLookup("n", "idx", "id", id)
                    .Match("p=(n)-[:RELATED_TO*0..2]-()")
                    .Return<PathsResult>("p");
IEnumerable<PathsResult> res = query.Results;
```

Each of the results in `res` should be what you're after?

Comment: That looks good. I'll need to create a PathsResult class though. Any ideas on that? Like what properties there'd need to be to get a path deserialised into it.

Comment: It's part of Neo4jclient, try putting: 'using Neo4jClient.ApiModels.Cypher;'

Comment: that does grab a path, yes. Thanks. However, the path is still comprised of the URLs of the nodes and relationships. How would I go from here to getting either objects or something that I could use to populate objects?

Comment: Okey dokes - What would be the *ideal* result from the query? Maybe a pseudo code version of the POCO?

Comment: I've edited my post with the sort of thing I've been doing up until now, without the lengthy code I was using to traverse the graph with Gremlin and check through each relation and pull back data. Basically, I'm not overly fussy how I get all the node and relationship properties along the path, as long as I get them relatively quickly and can put them to use.

Comment: Hmmm, I can't think of any nice way to get the results from the PathsResult class, aside from parsing the strings and taking the last number as an id for nodes / relationships and building it that way. I'm away for the next few days I'm afraid - but if you're still stuck will have a good go on Monday. neo4jclient does let you queue up stuff (I believe) to get the traffic low, I can't remember how - but the answer is on SO in the neo4jclient tag. Sorry about this.. pesky holidays :)

Comment: Thanks Chris, I don't sense any solution on the horizon so I'd be happy for any help you can give when you're back. I can have a play with parsing through the strings and getting nodes/relationships that way in the meantime unless anyone else has any ideas.

Comment: I've been looking around. It seems that the rest response will always come back in a restful format, i.e only giving you URIs. SO maybe there is no way of getting a useable path out. Interestingly, though, the webadmin cypher console outputs JSON as opposed to URIs. So the server can do it, it's just not exposed as part of the REST client.

Comment: I think the only way you're going to get the data back in the way you want it is to parse the returned PathsResult into a POCO you are happy with. I also don't think any of the other clients will be able to help you (short of using a native Java API) as they pretty much all use the REST API, and that only gives back data in the format we're getting now (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-cypher.html#rest-api-return-paths)

Comment: I have worked out the answer, but your clue about looking into PathsResult certainly helped me along the way. Thanks for the idea, you've been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I started with Chris Skardon's [code](https://bitbucket.org/cskardon/neo4jclient.pathsexample/src/2cd5a7b116fa6c98307662b0ec0a663146ba99e0/Neo4JClient.PathsExample/Program.cs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) (http://geekswithblogs.net/cskardon/archive/2013/07/23/neo4jclient-ndash-getting-path-results.aspx) and just started to remove the Relationship classes to see if it would work.  I like Chris' solution because it returns the node properties as well as the relationship (including TypeKey) in one go.  Turns out you don't need to create any new classes.

```
    var queryResults = graphClient.Cypher
                .Match("p=(n)-[:RELATED_TO|OTHER_RELATION*0..2]-()")
                .Return(p => new 
                {
                    Nodes = Return.As<IEnumerable<Node<**YOUR_NODE_CLASS**>>>("nodes(p)"),
                    Relationships = Return.As<IEnumerable<RelationshipInstance<Dictionary<string,string>>>>("rels(p)")
                })
                .Results; 
       resultsPath.Dump();//Use LINQPad to see the results
```

The relationship object that I used is `Dictionary<string,string>` (which you can use in place of `**YOUR_NODE_CLASS**`) - for me, there is no data in the `RelationshipReference.Data` field, but I think there would be if my relationship had properties.