# How do I retrieve a fully represented path in Neo4J's cypher rest API

Tags: neo4j

After discussing retrieving paths in .NET in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108301/how-do-i-retrieve-a-path-in-neo4jclient), I see why I've been having difficulties. I started running cypher queries directly against REST and found that when your query returns a path, it is returned in a RESTful manner, i.e the URIs for the nodes and relationships in question.

This has been causing me a fair amount of trouble. I need to retrieve the nodes themselves and their relationships. I know the server can do this, as running any path-style query on the server shell gets JSON objects that contain all the pathy goodness I'd be after. I don't think Neo4JClient has any way around this, since there's nothing to retrieve the path's nodes and relationships themselves through REST, at least as far as I can tell.

If it helps to have a context, I'm trying to retrieve paths from the database to display in a front end.

Is there any way of retrieving the nodes and relationships for a path in one, like can be done on the shell or in Java et al? If not, what is my best alternative? Should I try writing a plugin?

A simple sample REST request (copied from webadmin rest console) is below:

```
post /db/data/cypher { "query" : "start n = node:myindex(ID='1') MATCH p = n<-[:RELATED_TO]-m RETURN p;" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can return just the node IDs in Cypher like so:

```
start n=node:node_auto_index(name='Neo') 
match p=n-[r:KNOWS*]-m 
return EXTRACT( n in nodes(p) : id(n) ) as node_ids_on_path
```

? See http://console.neo4j.org/r/5a02od for an example

Comment: thanks for your answer. I took your example a step further, well, back actually, by just getting n from the extract and not the id of it. I think I've got the functionality I've been after here. Even better, with a little bit of tinkering, I've got it working nicely with Neo4JClient and I can now dispense with my inefficient Gremlin methods which were making several thousand calls to the database. I'll make a post later explaining how exactly I got here, in case it'd help anyone else.