# How do I return a Neo4j path with Neo4jClient in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

#### Summary

I'm trying to fetch a `path` from Neo4j using the Neo4jClient package in .NET.  I'm wondering how to deserialize it while maintaining the robust values featured in the `table` response, but I can only seem to access the `text` response instead.

***Disclaimer*** - I *have* seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108301/how-do-i-retrieve-a-path-in-neo4jclient), but it's over 7 years old and hardly relevant anymore — not to mention that the end result looks incredibly convoluted.

#### Technology Versions

- **Neo4j** - 4.2.3
- **APOC** - 4.2.0.1
- **Neo4jClient** - 4.1.5
- **.NET Framework** - 4.7.2

#### Data Structure

I have a Neo4j database that houses three types of nodes.  For the sake of this question, I'm going to water them down to a corporate example, so let's call the node labels `Employee`, `Department`, and `Project`.  Those nodes are interconnected in the following ways:

- Every `Employee` has an `EMPLOYED_BY` relationship with a `Department`.
- Every `Project` has an `OWNED_BY` relationship with a `Department`.
- An `Employee` could have a `WORKS_ON` relationship with a `Project`.

#### Sample Data

For the sake of this question, this sample data provides a baseline demonstration of the data structure.

```js
(:Employee {name:"Sarah Bradshaw"})
-[:EMPLOYED_BY {startDate:"2020-01-01"}]->
(:Department {name:"Finance"})
<-[:OWNED_BY {startDate:"2020-01-01"}]-
(:Project {name:"Quarterly Earnings"})
<-[:WORKS_ON {startDate:"2020-06-01"}]-
(:Employee {name:"Thomas Mitchell"})
-[:EMPLOYED_BY {startDate:"2019-01-01"}]->
(:Department {name:"Administration"})
```

[image: A visual representation of the above data.]

#### Cypher Query

This is the query I'm attempting to duplicate in .NET with the Neo4jClient package.

```js
MATCH (from:Employee {name:"Sarah Bradshaw"})
MATCH (to:Employee {name:"Thomas Mitchell"})
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(from, to, '', 'd')
YIELD path
RETURN path
```

#### Responses

**Table Response**

```json
{
    "start": {
        "identity": 0,
        "labels": [ "Employee" ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "Sarah Bradshaw"
        }
    },
    "end": {
        "identity": 3,
        "labels": [ "Employee" ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "Thomas Mitchell"
        }
    },
    "segments": [
        {
            "start": {
                "identity": 0,
                "labels": [ "Employee" ],
                "properties": {
                    "name": "Sarah Bradshaw"
                }
            },
            "relationship": {
                "identity": 0,
                "start": 0,
                "end": 1,
                "type": "EMPLOYED_BY",
                "properties": {
                    "startDate": "2020-01-01"
                }
            },
            "end": {
                "identity": 1,
                "labels": [ "Department" ],
                "properties": {
                    "name": "Finance"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "start": {
                "identity": 1,
                "labels": [ "Department" ],
                "properties": {
                    "name": "Finance"
                }
            },
            "relationship": {
                "identity": 1,
                "start": 2,
                "end": 1,
                "type": "OWNED_BY",
                "properties": {
                    "startDate": "2020-01-01"
                }
            },
            "end": {
                "identity": 2,
                "labels": [ "Project" ],
                "properties": {
                    "name": "Quarterly Earnings"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "start": {
                "identity": 2,
                "labels": [ "Project" ],
                "properties": {
                    "name": "Quarterly Earnings"
                }
            },
            "relationship": {
                "identity": 2,
                "start": 3,
                "end": 2,
                "type": "WORKS_ON",
                "properties": {
                    "startDate": "2020-06-01"
                }
            },
            "end": {
                "identity": 3,
                "labels": [ "Employee" ],
                "properties": {
                    "name": "Thomas Mitchell"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "length": 3.0
}
```

**Text Response**

```json
[
    {"name":"Sarah Bradshaw"},
    {"startDate":"2020-01-01"},
    {"name":"Finance"},
    {"name":"Finance"},
    {"startDate":"2020-01-01"},
    {"name":"Quarterly Earnings"},
    {"name":"Quarterly Earnings"},
    {"startDate":"2020-06-01"},
    {"name":"Thomas Mitchell"}
]
```

As you can see, the `text` response is basically useless.  Unfortunately, that seems to be the only response value I'm able to retrieve through the Neo4jClient.

#### Neo4jClient Query

This is the derived Neo4jClient syntax based on the above query.  Because I could only fetch the `text` response, I'm deserializing it into a `List` of type `DataNode` — a simple model that reflects the structure of the nodes and their relationships.

```js
client.Cypher
.Match("(from:Employee {name:\"Sarah Bradshaw\"})")
.Match("(to:Employee {name:\"Thomas Mitchell\"})")
.Call("apoc.algo.dijkstra(from, to, '', 'd')")
.Yield("path")
.Return<List<DataNode>>("path")
.ResultsAsync
.Result;
```

#### The Bottom Line

While this does get me *something*, the problem is that none of the things that make the path relevant are returned in the `text` response.  I have a collection of nodes and relationships, but I have no idea how they're interconnected.  The `table` response lists start nodes and end nodes and *that's* the information I care about.  Is there any way for me to query the `table` response rather than the `text` response?

Comment: `BoltGraphClient` or `GraphClient`?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've made an assumption you're using `BoltGraphClient` - as with `GraphClient` you're pretty much stuck as the REST endpoint doesn't give out the IDs you're after.

There is a class called `PathsResultBolt` in `Neo4jClient` - *but* it's giving out `System.Object` as the answer for every property in results of the query - which is less than useful, so you should try this class instead:

```
public class PathsResultBolt<TNode, TRel>
{
    public PathsResultBolt()
    {
        Nodes = new List<PathsResultBoltNode<TNode>>();
        Relationships = new List<PathsResultBoltRelationship<TRel>>();
    }

    internal PathsResultBolt(IPath path)
    {
        Start = new PathsResultBoltNode<TNode>(path.Start);
        End = new PathsResultBoltNode<TNode>(path.End);
        Relationships = path.Relationships.Select(r => new PathsResultBoltRelationship<TRel>(r)).ToList();
        Nodes = path.Nodes.Select(r => new PathsResultBoltNode<TNode>(r)).ToList();
    }

    [JsonProperty("Start")]
    public PathsResultBoltNode<TNode> Start { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("End")]
    public PathsResultBoltNode<TNode> End { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Length => Relationships.Count();

    [JsonProperty("Nodes")]
    public List<PathsResultBoltNode<TNode>> Nodes { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Relationships")]
    public List<PathsResultBoltRelationship<TRel>> Relationships { get; set; }

    public class PathsResultBoltRelationship<T>
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public long StartNodeId { get; set; }
        public long EndNodeId { get; set; }

        public object this[string key] => Properties[key];

        public Dictionary<string, T> Properties { get; set; }

        public PathsResultBoltRelationship() { Properties = new Dictionary<string, T>(); }

        public PathsResultBoltRelationship(IRelationship relationship)
        {
            Id = relationship.Id;
            StartNodeId = relationship.StartNodeId;
            EndNodeId = relationship.EndNodeId;
            Type = relationship.Type;
            Properties = relationship.Properties.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value.As<T>());
        }

        public bool Equals(PathsResultBoltRelationship<T> other)
        {
            if (other == null)
                return false;

            return Id == other.Id
                   && StartNodeId == other.StartNodeId
                   && EndNodeId == other.EndNodeId
                   && Type == other.Type
                   && Properties.ContentsEqual(other.Properties);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return Equals(obj as PathsResultBoltRelationship<T>);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            var hashCode = 2105322407;
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + Id.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(Type);
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + StartNodeId.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EndNodeId.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<IReadOnlyDictionary<string, T>>.Default.GetHashCode(Properties);
            return hashCode;
        }
    }

    public class PathsResultBoltNode<T>
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public List<string> Labels { get; set; }
        public object this[string key] => Properties[key];
        public Dictionary<string, T> Properties { get; set; }

        public PathsResultBoltNode() { Properties = new Dictionary<string, T>(); }

        internal PathsResultBoltNode(INode node)
        {
            Id = node.Id;
            Labels = node.Labels?.ToList();
            Properties = node.Properties.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value.As<T>());
        }

        public bool Equals(PathsResultBoltNode<T> other)
        {
            if (other == null)
                return false;

            return Id == other.Id
                   && Labels.ContentsEqual(other.Labels)
                   && Properties.ContentsEqual(other.Properties);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return Equals(obj as PathsResultBoltNode<T>);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            var hashCode = 1343812023;
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + Id.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<IReadOnlyList<string>>.Default.GetHashCode(Labels);
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<IReadOnlyDictionary<string, T>>.Default.GetHashCode(Properties);
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
}
```

Which you would use like so:

```
client.Cypher
  .Match("(from:Employee {name:\"Sarah Bradshaw\"})")
  .Match("(to:Employee {name:\"Thomas Mitchell\"})")
  .Call("apoc.algo.dijkstra(from, to, '', 'd')")
  .Yield("path")
  .Return<PathsResultBolt<string, string>>("path")
  .ResultsAsync
  .Result;
```

What is this `<string, string>` you ask? The first is the property type of the Nodes, the second is for the Relationships.

Now. This is a bit rubbish - and it's down to the fact I'm not sure how to get the actual object values to be proper `objects` which work. So the best approach (!!) is to use `string` for both node and rels at the moment. In my tests using the standard Movie database, I get this:

[image: Results of the query in LinqPad]

the `born` property is a `string` but that's the base level, using `int` would cause an error as `name` is *not* an int.